# How get terms of specific taxonomy in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I am working on properties project and need to get terms of specific taxonomy. I mean properties of cities base of their states.
Here is the code I have written for:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <?php 
                    $taxonomy = 'property-state';
                    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy); 
                    ?>
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>">
                                        <?php echo $term->name . '&nbsp;('. $term->count .')' ?>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <?php 
                    $taxonomy = 'property-city';
                    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy); 
                    ?>
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>">
                                        <?php echo $term->name . '&nbsp;('. $term->count .')'?>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php
                ?>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end of row -->
```

What I need is to list properties of cities base of state, how should I change these codes?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer myself, I wanted to list properties of specific state with specific status.
for example the properties of Kabul state with status of (for-rent) and the properties count on each city of that state.

```
<?php $terms = get_terms("property-city");

                foreach($terms as $term)
                {

                 
                $items = get_posts(array(
                        'numberposts'      => -1,
                        'post_type'        => 'property',
                        'post_status'      => 'publish',
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            'relation' => 'AND',
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'property-city',
                                'field'    => 'slug',
                                'terms'    => $term->slug
                            ),
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'property-state',
                                'field'    => 'name',
                                'terms'    => 'هرات',
                                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                            ),
                        )
                    ));

                $count =  count( $items );
                ?>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term);?>" <?php if ($count == 0) echo " style='display: none';"; ?>>
                                <?php echo $term->name. '&nbsp;('. $count .')';?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <?php
                
                }
                
                ?>
```